# Erro ao tentar salvar dados em duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Bom dia.
Ao fazer update em uma tabela o meu sistema tem que salvar os dados atuais numa tabela histórico e somente depois salvar os dados do formulário na tabela realizando o update.

Esta é a action que recebe o formulário para fazer o update, e logo chama o método SalvarHistorico:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ConsBritadorPRODId,LoginId,Data_inclusao,Hora_inclusao,Data_turno,Tempo_operacao_britador,Consumo_gipsita_britador,Consumo_gipsita_britada,Inicial_gas,Final_gas,Tempo_operacao_moinho,Producao_estuque,Turno_operacao,Observacoes")] ConsBritadorPROD consBritadorPROD)
    {
        var objlogin = db.Login.OrderByDescending(p => p.LoginId).FirstOrDefault();
        SalvarHistorico(consBritadorPROD.ConsBritadorPRODId);


        consBritadorPROD.Hora_inclusao = DateTime.Now;
        consBritadorPROD.Data_inclusao = DateTime.Today;
        consBritadorPROD.LoginId = objlogin.UsuarioId;

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(consBritadorPROD).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.LoginId = new SelectList(db.Login, "LoginId", "LoginId", consBritadorPROD.LoginId);
        //ViewBag.ID_Referencia = new SelectList(db.Referencias, "ID_Referencia", "ID_Referencia", consumo_britador_producao.ID_Referencia);
        return View(consBritadorPROD);
    }
```

O método SalvarHistorico é esse:

```
 public void SalvarHistorico(int? id)
    {
        if(id == null)
        {
            new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        try
        {
            var objlogin = db.Login.OrderByDescending(p => p.LoginId).FirstOrDefault();
            ConsBritadorPROD objBritador = db.ConsBritadorPRODs.Find(id);

            ConsBritadorProdHist histConsBritadorPROD = new ConsBritadorProdHist();

            histConsBritadorPROD.Hora_inclusao = DateTime.Now;
            histConsBritadorPROD.Data_inclusao = DateTime.Today;
            histConsBritadorPROD.LoginId = objlogin.UsuarioId;
            histConsBritadorPROD.ConsBritadorPRODId = objBritador.ConsBritadorPRODId;
            histConsBritadorPROD.Data_turno = objBritador.Data_turno;
            histConsBritadorPROD.Tempo_operacao_britador = objBritador.Tempo_operacao_britador;
            histConsBritadorPROD.Consumo_gipsita_britador = objBritador.Consumo_gipsita_britador;
            histConsBritadorPROD.Consumo_gipsita_britada = objBritador.Consumo_gipsita_britada;
            histConsBritadorPROD.Final_gas = objBritador.Final_gas;
            histConsBritadorPROD.Inicial_gas = objBritador.Inicial_gas;
            histConsBritadorPROD.Tempo_operacao_moinho = objBritador.Tempo_operacao_moinho;
            histConsBritadorPROD.Producao_estuque = objBritador.Producao_estuque;
            histConsBritadorPROD.Turno_operacao = objBritador.Turno_operacao;
            histConsBritadorPROD.Observacoes = objBritador.Observacoes;

            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.ConsBritadorProdHist.Add(histConsBritadorPROD);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

    }
```

No entanto quando eu executo aparece o erro abaixo:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Attaching an entity of type 'MES.Models.ConsBritadorPROD' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.'

Alguem poderia me ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certamente isso esta acontecendo porque seu objeto `ConsBritadorPROD` já esta no contexto, quando você faz o `Find` no seu método `SalvarHistorico` ele é carregando no contexto e mapeado.

```
ConsBritadorPROD objBritador = db.ConsBritadorPRODs.Find(id);
```

Você pode mudar o estado dele para Detached e depois anexar no contexto e novamente mudar para Modified.

```
var local = db.ConsBritadorProdHist.Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConsBritadorPRODId == consBritadorPROD.ConsBritadorPRODId);
if (local != null)
{
    db.Entry(local).State = EntityState.Detached;
}

db.ConsBritadorProdHist.Attach(consBritadorPROD);
db.Entry(consBritadorPROD).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Ou você pode tenta usar o `AsNoTracking` na sua consulta.

```
ConsBritadorPROD objBritador = db.Set<ConsBritadorProdHist>().AsNoTracking().First(x => x.ConsBritadorPRODId  == id);
```

Comment: Obrigado consegui com o Detached.